# Magento downloadable_link_purchased_item empty

Tags: php, magento

I have a magento CE 1.7.0.2 running and want to sell downloadable digital products (images). Something went wrong (I don't know exactly if ssl or extension). Now the DB-Table downloadable_link_purchased_item is not being updated, after a customer buys a product.

Does someone have any hints how can I solve this?

Comment: Hello guys. We found out an error via our logs, after some tests and reinstall of the Magento shop. Following message one gets in in the log: No cURL data returned for rentdim.dehttp://storage.googleapis.com/bucket/path/to/… [0] Could not resolve host: www.rentdim.dehttp Any suggestions how this broken link could appear? What can we try to fix in magento? Which php file? or update cURL? We would be so thankful for every hint. –  dimi